# Not able to change primary key name of authentication table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

when i execute the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

the result is

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'pk_bint_user_id' to appuser without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Please select a fix:

 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

And my model is look like as follows:

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    pk_bint_user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    ) 

    fk_bint_travel_agency_user_id_or_corporate_user_id= models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    chr_travel_agency_user_or_corporate_user =models.CharField('Agency user or Corporate user',max_length=5,blank=True,null=True)
    chr_user_type = models.CharField('User type code',max_length=5,blank=True,null=True)

    vchr_account_type=models.CharField('Account type',max_length=5,blank=True,null=True)
    vchr_account_status=models.CharField('Account status',max_length=5,blank=True,null=True)



    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    class Meta:
        db_table='tbl_user'
```

All i want to customize the primary key into different name than "id",

Answer (score 0):

is your database populated? I think that maybe your table of users is populated and you're trying to change the structure with the data.

if that field is not null and you have data in the users table then, as a database constraint you must do something.  I recommend that if you are just on develop and not in production delete the data from the user table and then fill it again, with the new structure

Comment: Actually i am developing the application from scratch. There are no tables in there, I am making the initial migration to get created the tables in my databse. :(